# Dialog box with options retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, telerik

I have a database table `Prospect` which stores prospects with primary key id & version. There is a radbutton `Generate Proposal` in a webform, which when clicked should display a dialog box to allow the user to select the version of the prospect to generate from a dropdown box. I have a method which will retrieve the versions from the database for the prospect `GetVersions()` but have no idea how to put it in a dialog box to allow the user to select the version. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Would JQuery UI be an option?

You would have to add the JQuery UI refferences which can be found [Here](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

[Here is the documentation on the JQuery UI dialog.](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

The below code was taken from a solution that I implemented. I have removed quite a few pieces of code for simplicity. Let me know if you need any clarification.

HTML:

```
<div id="MenuChangeSelection" title="Change Selection" class="MainDialog">
    <div id="MenuChangeSelectionContent"></div>
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
        $("#YourRadBtnID").click(function () {
            var yourDropDownMarkup = "<select><option value='Opt1'>Opt1</option></select>"; // Insert your dropdown markup or get your dropdown from the dom.
            $("#MenuChangeSelectionContent").html(yourDropDownMarkup);
            $("#MenuChangeSelection").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 600,
                height: 150,
                buttons: {
                    "Save And Close": function() {
                        //Do something when Save And Close is clicked. eg. asynchronously post back to server.
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                open: function () {
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('custom-overlay');
                },
                close: function () {
                    $('.ui-widget-overlay').removeClass('custom-overlay');
                }
            });
        });
```

CSS:

```
    .ui-widget-overlay.custom-overlay
    {
        background-color:black;
        opacity:0.4;
        filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a little snippet to get you started. This uses the [jQuery Dialog Box](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

In the aspx page

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<asp:Button ID="generateProposal" runat="server" Text="Generate Proposal" OnClick="generateProposal_Click" />

<div id="popupContent" style="display: none">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopup() {
        $(function () {
            $("#popupContent").dialog();
        });
    }
</script>
```

And then in code behind.

```
protected void generateProposal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the id of the prospect. Not clear from your question where this should come from
    int proposalID = 6;

    //sometimes a counter is just a counter
    int counter = 0;

    //clear old items from the dropdownlist
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

    //load the prospects from the database here and attach to dropdownlist
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("prospect_select", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = proposalID;

        try
        {
            //open the database connection
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            //loop all rows and add them to the dropdownlist
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(counter, new ListItem(reader["prospect_name"].ToString(), reader["prospect_version"].ToString(), true));
                counter++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //handle the error if you want
        }
    }

    //call the javascript function to open the dialog box
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showPopup", "showPopup();", true);
}
```